RabbitMq Client C#: issue when using async consumer : System.InvalidOperationException: Should never be called
Having issues when using RabbitMq Client in C# version 6.8.1 and running rabbit mq in docker.
i have a publisher which works fine, it published to a queue and i can see them in the management UI.
when running the consumer tho, the messages temporarly go to the unAcked with no logs, then when consumer is disconnected, messages return to ready.
i figured there must me an issue when recieving the messages, so i subscribed to ChannelCallbackException event in the consumer and by adding breakpoint i found this exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Should never be called.
   at RabbitMQ.Client.AsyncDefaultBasicConsumer.RabbitMQ.Client.IBasicConsumer.HandleBasicConsumeOk(String consumerTag)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ConcurrentConsumerDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<HandleBasicConsumeOk>b__0()

downloaded the client with the same version locally, it wouldn't due to some missing properties/dependancies which i couldnt understand why since it must be the same published code so it must be something missing on my side.
could not make much of the client code unfortunately.
the following is my consumer class which connectionstring = localhost

public abstract class RabbitMqTopicConsumer : IHostedService
{
    protected IServiceProvider Provider { get; }
    protected readonly ILogger<RabbitMqTopicConsumer> Logger;
    private readonly string _queueName;
    private readonly AsyncEventingBasicConsumer _consumer;
    private readonly string _deadLetterQueue;
    private readonly AsyncEventingBasicConsumer _deadLetterConsumer;
    private readonly IModel _channel;

    public RabbitMqTopicConsumer(IServiceProvider provider, ILogger<RabbitMqTopicConsumer> logger,
        string connectionString, string exchange, string queueName)
    {
        Provider = provider;
        Logger = logger;
        var factory = (provider.GetService(typeof(IConnectionFactory)) as IConnectionFactory)!.Get(connectionString);
        var channel = factory.CreateConnection().CreateModel(); 
        _queueName = queueName;
        var deadLetterExchange = queueName + "-dead-letter-exchange";
        _deadLetterQueue = queueName + "-dead-letter-queue";


        CreateExchangeAndQueue(channel, deadLetterExchange, _deadLetterQueue);
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "x-dead-letter-exchange", deadLetterExchange },
            { "x-delivery-limit", 5 },
            { "x-queue-type", "quorum" }
        };
        CreateExchangeAndQueue(channel, exchange, queueName, dictionary);
        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += MessageReceived;
        consumer.Shutdown += OnConsumerShutdown;
        channel.CallbackException += ChannelCallbackException;
        channel.FlowControl += FlowControlEvent;
        // channel.
        _consumer = consumer;
        _channel = channel;
        _deadLetterConsumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        _deadLetterConsumer.Received += DeadLetterReceived;
    }

    private void FlowControlEvent(object? sender, FlowControlEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void ChannelCallbackException(object? sender, CallbackExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString());
    }

    private async Task OnConsumerShutdown(object sender, ShutdownEventArgs @event)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@event.Cause.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(@event.ReplyText);
        Console.WriteLine(@event.ReplyCode.ToString());
    }

    private async Task DeadLetterReceived(object? sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" dead letter consumed message [x] Received {0}", e.RoutingKey);
        _channel.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceived(object? model, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea)
    {
        byte[] body = ea.Body.ToArray();
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        Console.WriteLine($" [x] {message}");
        
        var result = await HandleMessageAsync(message, model, ea);
        if (result)
            _channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
        else
            _channel.BasicReject(ea.DeliveryTag, true);
        await Task.Yield();
    }

    private void CreateExchangeAndQueue(IModel channel, string exchange, string queue,
        Dictionary<string, object>? arguments = null)
    {
        channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange, ExchangeType.Fanout, durable: true, autoDelete: false);
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: arguments);
        channel.QueueBind(queue, exchange, string.Empty);
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _channel.BasicConsume(queue: _queueName,
            autoAck: false,
            exclusive: false,
            consumer: _consumer);

        _channel.BasicConsume(queue: _deadLetterQueue,
            autoAck: false,
            exclusive: false,
            consumer: _deadLetterConsumer);

      Console.ReadLine();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }


    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _channel.Dispose();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected abstract Task<bool> HandleMessageAsync(object serviceBusMessage, object? model, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea);
}

